# Setting innerHTML/html() on DOM-elements within nested loop - IE performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer, dom

I am working on some horrible legacy code where a JSON-object is fetched from the server. The object is a list of IDs that correspond to DOM-Nodes. Each list-item contains new HTML-Code-Snippets to be inserted for that node. Basically it looks like this:

```
var $table = $("#theTable");
var tableData = getData();

for (var row in tableData) {

     // find the TR
     var $row = $table.find('tr[data-id=' + row + ']');

     // update many sub-elements of the TR (~100-1000 nodes)
     for (var el in row) {
           var $el = $row.find("td[data-element='" + el + "']");
           if ($el.length) {
                 $el[0].innerHTML = row[el];
           }
     }
}
```

Obviously it is bad practice to select nodes or call .innerHTML/.html() within a loop, but at this point there is no other choice. This results in very bad performance especially in IE. I tried to hide/detach the node, before doing the updates, reattaching/showing it again when everything is done, but it did not improve performance what so ever - it just got worse.

Is there any way to easily speed this up?

Comment: Yeh, applying additional processing like hide/detach will just decrease performance. I honestly don't think you'll be able to improve this without changing the overall implementation :-(

Comment: can't you render the wohle `table` or `TR`s in php instead of running this nested loops?

Comment: Agree with @Chris. Makes more sense to recreate the table HTML and insert in one go.

Comment: I agree as well, but at this point there is no time for this :/

Comment: working with IDs? `$row.find("td[data-element='" + el + "']");` is slower than `$('#td-'+el')`